# Yup validate number only, avoide e, E, -, + characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I'm new here. I have an issue with Yup validation. I want client enter number only from 0-9, without entering `e, E, +, -` characters. I have code like this but user still can enter e, +, -. Is there any way to avoide these characters?

```
Yup.number()
  .typeError("Please enter number value only")
  .nullable()
  .notRequired()
  .min(0)
  .max(100)
  .moreThan(-1, "Negative values not accepted")
```

I try with `string().matches(regex)` but it still showing err with negative values. Is there the best way to use `.number()` without these characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a custom validator with the `test` method:

```js
Yup
  .number()
  .nullable()
  .notRequired()
  .min(0)
  .max(100)
  .test(
    "noEOrSign", // type of the validator (should be unique)
    "Number had an 'e' or sign.", // error message
    (value) => typeof value === "number" && !/[eE+-]/.test(value.toString())
  );
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer resolved my question. I just need to edit some parts and it works now. Thank you

Comment: Didn't work for me, as when I type '2e2' in input, value of test converts it into 200(2*e^2). So even if input has the `e`, yup test fails to realize that.